# node serving react working locally but not on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I made a simple create-react-app application and a node.js express server side.
locally this works (server serves ui and do api) but when deploying to heroku
only UI is served (any API call gets a 503 code)

**App.js**

```
// Routes

// works both locally and on heroku
app.get('/ui', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'build','index.html'));
});

// works only locally
app.use('/users',users);
app.use('/pledge',pledge);
```

**React router**

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <div>
                    <Router history={history}>
                        <div>
                            <Route path={'/ui/'} component={Header}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path='/ui/welcome' component={Welcome}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path="/ui/login" component={Login}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path="/ui/help" component={Help}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path="/ui/dashboard" component={DashBoard}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path='/ui/logout' component={Logout}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path='/ui/pledge' component={Pledge}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path='/ui/buckets' component={Bucket}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path='/ui/add' component={AddStuff}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path='/ui/motion' component={MotionInput}/>
                            <Route exact={true} path='/ui/status' component={Status}/>
                        </div>
                    </Router>
                </div>
            </ThemeProvider>
```

No server side rendering. example for API:

```
app.post('/usersAdd',(req, res) => {

  let newUser = new User(req.body);
  newUser.save((err) => {
    if (err)
      return res.send(500, {error: err});

    return res.send("successfully saved");
  });
});
```

**API call**

```
export function getUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(serverProps.server + serverProps.getUsers, {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        })
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject);
    });
}
```

Comment: are you using express ?

Comment: yes I am. Need any additional code?

Answer (score 0):

It's because on deploying, when going to route `/users` it looks for any file named users.html and doesn't find it, so returns 503. You can fix it by redirecting all routes to `index.html` by replacing your `app.get` call with:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Have a look [here](https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d). See if it works.

Comment: thank you, however now the server side API calls like /users are not working and i get an html page

Comment: I dont understand how API calls get affected by this. Are you using server side rendering ? Could you share code if u can ?

Comment: I've seen your code, I need to know how you hit these APIs in the frontend. Do u use axios ?

Comment: yes, both axios post and get, I've added this to my questiong

Comment: have you removed these lines: `app.use('/users',users);
app.use('/pledge',pledge);`. If yes, then I cant say what's causing the problem with given code. Maybe some issue with how you use axios.

Comment: these lines: app.use('/users',users); app.use('/pledge',pledge); are server API calls, I wanted to use this node app to both serve the UI and host the API.